# Combine word documents in hyperlink list

Tags: excel, vba, merge, ms-word, hyperlink

I am new in the world of VBA. I would look for help for my problem.

I have list of file in range B3:40. In each cells, hyperlink to specific word document (.docx) file in the communal server.

Now, I would like to combine all documents in the hyperlink list in that range to become one new word document that contain all documents in the list using VBA excel.

Below is my code. I just can open it, but don't know how to combine it.

Thank you in advance for any help.

```
Dim xhyperlink as Hyperlink
Dim Openfile as Range
On Error Resume Next

Set Openfile = Thisworkbook.Sheets("name of sheet")
Set Openfile = Range ("B3:B40")

For Each xhyperlink In Openfile.Hyperlinks
xhyperlink.Follow
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a quicker response in the future ask a specific question about your code, "Is it possible?" is not a good question.  If you are not sure how code something in Word/Excel try the Macro recorder first.  Then post the specific issue you are having with the code.  That being said Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Here's a new account freebie answer...

Add the `Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library` Reference through Tools --> References.

```
Sub MergeDocs()
    Dim oLink As Hyperlink
    Dim oLinkRange As Range
    
    ' Set Range of Hyperlinks
    Set oLinkRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")
    
    'Setup "Merge" Document
    Dim oWord As New Word.Application
    Dim oMergeDoc As Word.Document
    Set oMergeDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
    
    'Insert Files into Master
    For Each oLink In oLinkRange.Hyperlinks
        oWord.Selection.InsertFile (oLink.Address)
    Next
    
    'Save Merged Document & Close
    oMergeDoc.SaveAs2 ("C:\Temp\MergeTest\Merged.docx")
    oMergeDoc.Close
    oWord.Quit
End Sub
```

Note: You'll want to add some error checking in there.

Comment: thank you for your help and suggestion @JosephC, I'll do better question next time. And for your code, I already tried it and found error about file address. It said that couldn't find the file (run time error 5174).